# Can a Interpreted language have a entry point

Tags: c, compilation, interpreter, entry-point, interpretation

I want to know, do only compiler based languages use a entry point, or if a interpreter based language can also use entry points, if yes then please give 1 example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point so many languages to choose from. Perl, PHP, Ruby are interpreted. Also "beginning of a script" is also an entry point.

Comment: Perl is compiled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shell scripts starts at the beginning of the script file. A python program starts at the beginning of the python file. In both cases you can call that the "entry" point.

The decision, if a program starts at the beginning of the file (like in both the examples above) or starts at a specific function (like `main`) has nothing to do with the decision to make a language compiled or interpreted. It is a mere language design consideration.

**Addition**
It is actually a quite common for example in python to do something like

```
# include statements and
# class definitions and
# function definitions go here

def main():
    pass    
    #do main stuff here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This defines a main function and the first non-definition statement calls it, if the module is the main program file.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way a program is started in Linux is by a shell calling fork+execve.  The new process is loaded and begins execution at the entry point specified by the format of the executable; for example ELF. In the case of an interpreted language, the executable is the interpreter specified on the first line after #! such as /usr/bin/python.